# Weird spacing issue mid-paragraph when using natbib, microtype, flowfram and the charter BT font

Tags: natbib, microtype, mathdesign, flowfram

I'm using `natbib`, `microtype`, `flowfram` and the charter BT font (through the command `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`), and I'm getting the following results:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/N4QrPee.png?2]

Other instances in my main document show this (maybe it's a clue to you):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5EuwMHw.png?2]

This is the code to generate the file:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage{flowfram}


\newflowframe[1-4,6]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]

\setlength\parindent{16pt}

\begin{document}

\tolerance=10000
The manufacturing process is mostly subject to industrial legislation. Although the industrial process is a relatively large actor in the use of fossil fuels\citep{voorzanger2014}, the consideration of usage of renewable energy sources has many hurdles. The primary hurdle is the artificially deflated pricing on energy from non-renewables. Studies on feasibility of an adjustment and usage of renewable energy sources in the industrial sector have shown legislation is in fact a culprit, linking domestical industrial activities directly to current energy policies in place\citep{lund2009}. Furthermore, an example of an accessible legislation is the Extended Producer Responsibility (EPR), which indirectly circumvents additional energy costs by incentivising recollection and reuse of products\citep{kiddee2013}. Other directives also geared towards promotion of recycling and take-back more so circumvent a change in thinking of the legislative bodies dealing with the industrial energy sector, which is why a small portion of examples will be discussed in the recycling cycle rather than here.

However, mobile phones also use REEs, ranging from scandium for high performance equipment, to neodymium for ear speakers\citep{website:namibiaearth,humphries2010}: vital components for the production of a cellular phone. The shortage depletion risk ranges even further however. Estimates have shown that REEs range in depletion risk from 500 years for niobium to 7 years for antimony, considering stable demand\citep{website:mining}.
\end{document}
```

I produced this weird spacing issue on both dated TL13 as well as extremely recent TL14 distributions. I always run a full installation for all packages.

I also notice that this *only* happens in the left column, not for any other columns I declared through e.g.:

```
\newflowframe{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3+\columnsep}{0pt}[centercolumn]
\newflowframe{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{\dimexpr2\textwidth/3-4\columnsep/3+2\columnsep}{0pt}[rightcolumn]
```

Is this a known issue and/or does it have a workaround?

Comment: `\tolerance=10000` means you are explicitly telling TeX you don't care how bad the linebreaking is. So it's not surprising that it is bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\tolerance=10000` means you are explicitly telling TeX you don't care how bad the linebreaking is. So it's not surprising that it is bad.

Removing the `\tolerance` setting tells TeX to at least try to make some reasonable output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage{flowfram}


\newflowframe[1-4,6]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]

\setlength\parindent{16pt}

\begin{document}

%\tolerance=10000
The manufacturing process is mostly subject to industrial legislation. Alth\-ough the industrial process is a relatively large actor in the use of fossil fuels\citep{voorzanger2014}, the consideration of usage of renewable energy sources has many hurdles. The primary hurdle is the artificially deflated pricing on energy from non-renewables. Studies on feasibility of an adjustment and usage of renewable energy sources in the industrial sector have shown legislation is in fact a culprit, linking domestical industrial activities directly to current energy policies in place\citep{lund2009}. Furthermore, an example of an accessible legislation is the Extended Producer Responsibility (EPR), which indirectly circumvents additional energy costs by incentivising recollection and reuse of products\citep{kiddee2013}. Other directives also geared towards promotion of recycling and take-back more so circumvent a change in thinking of the legislative bodies dealing with the industrial energy sector, which is why a small portion of examples will be discussed in the recycling cycle rather than here.

However, mobile phones also use REEs, ranging from scandium for high performance equipment, to neodymium for ear speakers\citep{website:namibiaearth,humphries2010}: vital components for the production of a cellular phone. The shortage depletion risk ran\-ges even further however. Estimates have shown that REEs range in depletion risk from 500 years for niobium to 7 years for antimony, considering stable demand\citep{website:mining}.
\end{document}
```